# How can i get search result based on Search By Field value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can i specify Search field based on the dropdown value selected?

I have this dropdown to specify which filed

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "mr-2" })
       .Name("SearchBy")
       .DataTextField("Text")
       .DataValueField("Value")
       .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
          new SelectListItem() {
               Text = "CompanyName",
               Value = ""
              },
          new SelectListItem() {
               Text = "Address",
               Value = ""
             }
            })
          )
```

My conditions are:

If user select `Name` from Search By dropdown then i need the search result to be only from `CompanyName` if user select Address I need the search to look `AddressLine1`, `AddressLine2`, `City`, `State`

I have this linq query receives two parameters, S

```
  var company = await Context.CompanySearch.AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(p => p.CompanyName.Contains(request.searchTerm) && p.compType == request.compType 
                        || (p.AddressLine1.Contains(request.searchTerm) && p.compType == request.compType )
                        || (p.AddressLine2.Contains(request.searchTerm) && p.compType == request.compType )
                        || (p.City.Contains(request.searchTerm) && p.compType == request.compType)
                        || (p.State.Contains(request.searchTerm) && p.compType== request.compType))
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToListAsync();
```

My controller looks like this

```
   [HttpGet]      
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanies(string searchTerm, string compType )
    {
        var result = await EntitiesService.GetEntitiesBySearchTerm(searchTerm, compType);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Do i have to pass the third parameter `Searchby`? if that is the case how can i update the linq query to specify which field to look for?

Comment: Your best option is to use `.AsQueryable()` and then a simple `if searchby=name  query.Where by name...` rather than trying to build the linq dynamically with the fieldname as a string (which isn't quite the case as you want address to search multiple fields anyway).  Can provide a more detailed answer if you'll consider this approach.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to pass that you only want to search by a specific field/group of fields. How is `entityType` used?

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry for the confusion my bad it suppose to say `compType` updated my question, and I have a field called compType it has only 3 constant value

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you that works!